# Angular 16 signals side effects

Tags: angular16, angular-signals

Before signals, I had an observable that I would watch to trigger a `FormControl`'s editable property, like this:

```js
this.#isItEditor$
    .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.#destroyRef))
    .subscribe(x => {
        const funded = this.formGroup.controls.funded
        if (x)
            funded.enable()
        else
            funded.disable()
    })
```

Now I've changed from an observable to a signal, but it feels like, in this case, I still need to create an observable from the signal to then do the `pipe`/`subscribe` the same way I used to.

I'm not assigning anything based on the signal changing, I'm just implementing a side effect.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use effect to listen signal changes. Effect will track signal reads and whenever value changes effect runs again.

```js
effect(() => {
  this.#isItEditor(); //Read signal here
  //Rest of the logic
    const funded = this.formGroup.controls.funded
    if (x)
        funded.enable()
    else
        funded.disable()
  
});
```

Comment: It seems like, using an `effect`, any time any signal runs it would have to process all of them. Is that true? If so, I'd probably be better letting it convert to an `Observable`.

Comment: effect only runs whenever their dependencies change